# how to solve this error "Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails" in java

Tags: java, mysql

here I am having three tables `ringeeUser, event , eventuserrelation` . `ringee_user_id` and `event_id` are foreign key in `eventuserrelation` table .
now I am trying to add a data or insert a data to eventuserrelation table I got a error like this

```
error while adding user relation for event id5

Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`ringeeapp_dev`.`event_user_relation`, CONSTRAINT `FK_EVT_RINGEE_USER_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`RINGEE_USER_ID`) REFERENCES `ringee_user` (`RINGEE_USER_ID`))
```

here I am post the code for addeventUserrelationDAOImpl

```
@Override
    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, isolation = Isolation.READ_COMMITTED)
    public List<EventUserRelationDO> addEventUserRelationMapping(ArrayList<UserDO> userDOs, long eventId) throws UserDataException {
        JdbcTemplate jd = this.getJdbctemplate();
        int totalAdded = 0;
        int IS_DELETE = IRingeeConstants.IS_NOT_DELETED;
        int IS_INVITE = IRingeeConstants.IS_NOT_INVITED;
        List<EventUserRelationDO> eventUserRelationDOLst = new ArrayList<EventUserRelationDO>(userDOs.size());
        for (UserDO userDO : userDOs) {
            try {
                long ringeeUserId = userDO.getRingeeUserId();
                Long eventUserRelationId = jd.queryForObject(EVENT_USER_RELATION_KEY, Long.class);
                jd.update(ADD_EVENT_USER_RELATION_MAPPING, new Object[] { eventUserRelationId, eventId, ringeeUserId, IS_INVITE, IS_DELETE });
                /*EventUserRelationDO eventUserRelationDO = new EventUserRelationDO();
                eventUserRelationDO.setEventUserRelationId(eventUserRelationId);
                eventUserRelationDO.setEventId(eventId);
                eventUserRelationDO.setRingeeUserId(ringeeUserId);
                eventUserRelationDOLst.add(eventUserRelationDO);*/
            } catch (DuplicateKeyException dExp) {
                Long eventUserExistId = jd.queryForObject(GET_USER_RELATION_EXIST_KEY, Long.class, new Object[] { eventId, userDO.getRingeeUserId() });
                int isAdded = jd.update(UPDATE_EVENT_USER_RELATION, new Object[] { 0, 0, eventUserExistId });
                totalAdded = totalAdded + isAdded;
            } catch (EmptyResultDataAccessException empExp) {
                throw new UserDataException("emtpy user relation key returned" + eventId, empExp);
            } catch (DataAccessException dExp) {
                throw new UserDataException("error while adding user relation for event id" + eventId, dExp);
            }
        }
        return eventUserRelationDOLst;
    }
```

this is the code for addEventUserRelationServiceImpl

```
@Override
    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
    public int addEventUserRealtionMapping(ArrayList<UserBO> userBOs, long eventId) throws UserServiceException {

        List<EventUserRelationDO> totalAddedCount;
        ArrayList<UserDO> userDOs = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            for (UserBO userBO : userBOs) {
                UserDO userDO = mapper.mapUserBOToDO(userBO, new UserDO());
                userDOs.add(userDO);
            }

            EventBO eventBO = getEventByEventId(eventId);
            MessageBO messageBO = new MessageBO();
            messageBO.setEventId(eventBO.getEventId());
            messageBO.setEventTitle(eventBO.getText());
            messageBO.setMessage(eventBO.getText());
            messageBO.setRingeeUserId(eventBO.getRingeeUserId());
            messageBO.setMessageType(IRingeeConstants.MESSAGE_TYPE_INVITATION);
            totalAddedCount = eventDAOImpl.addEventUserRelationMapping(userDOs, eventId);
            if (totalAddedCount.size() == userDOs.size()) {
                manageMessageService.sendMessageToGroup(userBOs, messageBO);
            }
        } catch (UserDataException dExp) {
            throw new UserServiceException(" exception while adding user relationship for eventId " + eventId, dExp);
        }
        return totalAddedCount.size();
    }
```

this is the code for testcase of addEventuserrelation in service layer

```
@Test
    @Rollback(false)
    public void addEventUserRealtionMapping() {
        ArrayList<UserBO> userBOs = new ArrayList<>();
        EventBO eventBO = getEventBO();
        UserBO userBO = getUserBO();
        userBOs.add(getUserBO1());

        try {
            manageUserServiceImpl.addUser(userBO);
            eventBO.setRingeeUserId(userBO.getRingeeUserId());
            manageEventServiceImpl.addEvent(eventBO);
            int addedTotalCount = manageEventServiceImpl.addEventUserRealtionMapping(userBOs, eventBO.getEventId());
            Assert.assertEquals(userBOs.size(), addedTotalCount);
        } catch (UserServiceException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Assert.fail();
        }

    }
```

here only I got the error above I mentioned.

this is the code for adduser (this is  for ur reference)

```
@Override
    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
    public void addEvent(EventDO eventDO) throws UserDataException {
        JdbcTemplate jd = this.getJdbctemplate();
        long userId = eventDO.getRingeeUserId();
        try {
            long eventId = jd.queryForObject(EVENT_KEY, Long.class);
            int isAdded = jd.update(ADD_EVENT, eventId, userId, eventDO.getText(), eventDO.getPlace(), eventDO.getEventDate(), eventDO.getStartTime(), eventDO.getEndTime(), eventDO.getIsDelete());
            // setting event id which is newly generated
            if (isAdded == 0) {
                throw new UserDataException("Adding new event count returns zero, hence insertion of new event failed for user " + userId);
            }
            eventDO.setEventId(eventId);
        } catch (DataAccessException dExp) {
            throw new UserDataException("Error while adding new event for user id " + userId, dExp);
        }
}
```

this is ADDEVENT query

```
private static final String ADD_EVENT = "INSERT EVENT (EVENT_ID, RINGEE_USER_ID, TEXT, PLACE, EVENT_DATE, START_TIME, END_TIME, IS_DELETE) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
```

this is the code for addUser

```
@Override
    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
    public void addUser(UserDO userDO) throws UserDataException {
        long userId = 0;
        JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = this.getJdbctemplate();
        try {
            userId = jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(USER_KEY, Long.class);
            userDO.setRingeeUserId(userId);
            int isAddedUser = jdbcTemplate.update(ADD_USER, new Object[] { userId, userDO.getUserName(), userDO.getRegistrationId(), userDO.getImeiCode(), userDO.getMobileNumber() });
            if (isAddedUser == 0)
                throw new UserDataException("Adding new user failed");
        } catch (DuplicateKeyException dupkeyExp) {
            log.debug("dupliate user , either mobile number, imei code or register id matches with existing user");
            System.out.println("dupliate user , either mobile number, imei code or register id matches with existing user");
            UserDO foundUserDO = isUserExists(userDO);
            if (null == foundUserDO) {
                log.debug("user neither available nor able to add new user , situation is unrealistic");
                throw new UserDataException("user neither available nor able to add new user , situation is unrealistic");
            }

            // case 1 :- when both mobile and imei code are same then
            // considering user uses same mobile
            // to login in app again, in this scenario we update user details
            // we are updating user details in this case, since user might get
            // assigned new google registration id, hence updating the user
            // details
            if (userDO.getImeiCode().equals(foundUserDO.getImeiCode()) && userDO.getMobileNumber().equals(foundUserDO.getMobileNumber())) {
                log.error("Already installed device user id " + userId);
                userDO.setRingeeUserId(foundUserDO.getRingeeUserId());
                int isUserUpdated = jdbcTemplate.update(UPDATE_USER,
                        new Object[] { userDO.getUserName(), userDO.getRegistrationId(), userDO.getImeiCode(), userDO.getDeleted(), foundUserDO.getRingeeUserId() });
                if (isUserUpdated == 0)
                    throw new UserDataException("updating user failed");
                // case 2 :- when mobile number and imei code not matching, then
                // consider that user user different mobile
                // to login app, this is very important scenario, since many
                // ways this can happen.
                // 1. one user downloaded app on a mobile , registered and later
                // he transfers mobile to another user, and he uses different
                // mobile
                // to login , here mobile number will be different , but imei
                // code is same
                // 2. same user same mobile , but uses different mobile number
                // in both cases, we make first user deactivate and new user
                // activate with that mobile number
            } else if (userDO.getImeiCode().equals(foundUserDO.getImeiCode()) && !userDO.getMobileNumber().equals(foundUserDO.getMobileNumber())) {
                // set deleted = 1, deactivating already existing/registered
                // user, since new mobile number getting assigned to this mobile
                foundUserDO.setDeleted(1);
                int isUserUpdated = jdbcTemplate.update(UPDATE_USER, new Object[] { foundUserDO.getUserName(), foundUserDO.getRegistrationId(), foundUserDO.getImeiCode(), foundUserDO.getDeleted(),
                        foundUserDO.getRingeeUserId() });
                if (isUserUpdated == 1) {
                    // calling recursive method to add user after found user
                    // deactivated.
                    addUser(userDO);
                } else if (isUserUpdated == 0) {
                    throw new UserDataException("deacitivation existing user and add new user for the mobile number " + userDO.getMobileNumber() + " failed");
                }

            } else {
                // if already user return 0
                userDO.setRingeeUserId(0);
            }
        } catch (DataAccessException dataAccExp) {
            throw new UserDataException("User Registration Failed", dataAccExp);
        }
    }
```

this is the query for ADDUSER

```
private static final String ADD_USER = "INSERT RINGEE_USER (RINGEE_USER_ID, USER_NAME, REGISTRATION_ID, IMEI_CODE, MOBILE_NUMBER, CREATED_DTTM) VALUES ( ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP())";
```

Comment: You should probably read this : http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: thanks for your reply here I am adding the code for complete reference